# Different results for the same query

Tags: sql, mysql, hibernate, c3p0

my name is Enrico Bonacina and I have very big problem after I moved my old application to a new Ubuntu Server.
The problem is that I have different results from the same query called
more and more times.

The application language is Java 1.7, is a web application using GWT 2.5 and Tomcat 7.0
On the server side I use Hibernate 4.3.11 with C3p0 0.9.2.1 to dialog with Mysql 5.5.7.
On the server is running Java Jdk 11.0.19

**My Persistence.xml is:**

```
#
# #==============================================================================================
# Configurazione dei database SERVER e LOCAL
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Aggiornamenti:
#   05/01/2022 - E. Bonacina - prima release
#
# ...Definizioni per Hibernate/JPA
#
org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix=_aud
hibernate.connection.pool_size=1
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 1
hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size = 1
hibernate.show_sql = false
hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer = false
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.autocommit=false
connection_provider_class = org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
hibernate.c3p0.min_size = 5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size = 20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout = 300
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements = 50
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period = 3000
hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery = SELECT 1
hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThread = 10
hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime = 10
hibernate.c3p0.contextClassLoaderSource = library
#
# SERVER - (Fie_new su db locale)
#
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update
hibernate.connection.username = 'uername'
hibernate.connection.password = 'password'
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3308/'dbname
```

**When I call more and more times the follow method:**

```
public java.util.List<it.eb.fie.persistence.model.Anagrafica> listAll(Set<String> ruoli, String username, Long associazioneId, Integer stagione) {
    
    EntityManager em = getSession();
    em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
    if(em.isJoinedToTransaction()) {
        SystemUtils.info("AnagraficaDAO.listAll - eseguito flush");
        em.flush();
    }
    List<Anagrafica> lAnagrafica = new ArrayList<Anagrafica>();
    if (ruoli.contains("anagrafica_visualizza_associazione") || ruoli.contains("anagrafica_visualizza_tutto")) {
        //
        // ...Query 
        //
        String queryString = "from it.eb.fie.persistence.model.AnagraficaAssociazioneSport p where 1=1 and p.evento.id IS NULL";
        queryString = queryString + " AND " + "p.associazioneSport.associazione.id = :associazioneId";
        queryString = queryString + " AND " + "p.stagione = :stagione";
        queryString = queryString + " AND " + "p.dzFigure.id = 4";
        queryString = queryString + " ORDER BY p.anagrafica.cognome, p.anagrafica.nome";
        javax.persistence.Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);
        query.setParameter("stagione", stagione);
        query.setParameter("associazioneId", associazioneId);
        
        List<it.eb.fie.persistence.model.AnagraficaAssociazioneSport> lAas = query.getResultList();
        SystemUtils.info("AnagraficaDAO.listAll - trovati: " + lAas.size() + " record");
        //
        // ...Test with native query
        //
        queryString = "select SQL_NO_CACHE aas.id from anagraficaassociazionesport aas";
        queryString = queryString + " " + "inner join associazionesport asp on asp.id = aas.associazionesport_id";
        queryString = queryString + " " + "inner join associazione ass on ass.id = asp.associazione_id";
        queryString = queryString + " " + "inner join anagrafica a on a.id = aas.anagrafica_id";
        queryString = queryString + " " + "WHERE evento_id IS NULL";
        queryString = queryString + " " + "AND ass.id = :associazioneId";
        queryString = queryString + " " + "AND aas.stagione = :stagione";
        queryString = queryString + " " + "AND aas.dzFigure_id = 4";
        query = em.createNativeQuery(queryString);
        query.setParameter("stagione", stagione);
        query.setParameter("associazioneId", associazioneId);
        SystemUtils.info("ChiamataNativa  - trovati: " + query.getResultList().size() + " record");
        //
        // ...Carica le anagrafiche
        //
        if(lAas != null && lAas.size() > 0) {
            for(AnagraficaAssociazioneSport aas : lAas) {
                Anagrafica a = aas.getAnagrafica();
                a.setNumeroTessera(aas.getNumeroTessera());
                a.setDataTesseramento(aas.getDataTesseramento());
                a.setTessera(aas.getTessera());
                lAnagrafica.add(a);
            }
        }
    } else {
        String queryString = "from it.eb.fie.persistence.model.Anagrafica p where p.username = :username";
        javax.persistence.Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);
        query.setParameter("username", username);
        query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.retriveMode", "BYPASS");
        lAnagrafica = query.getResultList();
    }
    em.close();
    return lAnagrafica
```

**The result written on the log file is:**

```
http-apr-8080-exec-7-05/06/23 17:27:07.398 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN AnagraficaDAO.listAll - trovati: 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-7-05/06/23 17:27:07.402 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN ChiamataNativa  - trovati: 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-7-05/06/23 17:27:07.404 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN getListaAnagrafica - trovati 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-1-05/06/23 17:27:14.778 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN AnagraficaDAO.listAll - trovati: 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-1-05/06/23 17:27:14.782 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN ChiamataNativa  - trovati: 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-1-05/06/23 17:27:14.784 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN getListaAnagrafica - trovati 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-2-05/06/23 17:30:53.156 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN AnagraficaDAO.listAll - trovati: 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-2-05/06/23 17:30:53.160 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN ChiamataNativa  - trovati: 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-2-05/06/23 17:30:53.161 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN getListaAnagrafica - trovati 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-4-05/06/23 17:30:56.830 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN AnagraficaDAO.listAll - trovati: 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-4-05/06/23 17:30:56.833 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN ChiamataNativa  - trovati: 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-4-05/06/23 17:30:56.834 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN getListaAnagrafica - trovati 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-8-05/06/23 17:31:00.727 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN AnagraficaDAO.listAll - trovati: 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-8-05/06/23 17:31:00.730 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN ChiamataNativa  - trovati: 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-8-05/06/23 17:31:00.731 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN getListaAnagrafica - trovati 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-3-05/06/23 17:31:02.127 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN AnagraficaDAO.listAll - trovati: 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-3-05/06/23 17:31:02.131 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN ChiamataNativa  - trovati: 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-3-05/06/23 17:31:02.132 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN getListaAnagrafica - trovati 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-9-05/06/23 17:31:03.736 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN AnagraficaDAO.listAll - trovati: 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-9-05/06/23 17:31:03.740 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN ChiamataNativa  - trovati: 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-9-05/06/23 17:31:03.741 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN getListaAnagrafica - trovati 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-6-05/06/23 17:31:05.868 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN AnagraficaDAO.listAll - trovati: 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-6-05/06/23 17:31:05.871 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN ChiamataNativa  - trovati: 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-6-05/06/23 17:31:05.872 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN getListaAnagrafica - trovati 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-5-05/06/23 17:31:07.338 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN AnagraficaDAO.listAll - trovati: 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-5-05/06/23 17:31:07.342 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN ChiamataNativa  - trovati: 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-5-05/06/23 17:31:07.343 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN getListaAnagrafica - trovati 56 record
http-apr-8080-exec-10-05/06/23 17:31:08.658 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN AnagraficaDAO.listAll - trovati: 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-10-05/06/23 17:31:08.661 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN ChiamataNativa  - trovati: 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-10-05/06/23 17:31:08.662 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN getListaAnagrafica - trovati 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-7-05/06/23 17:31:10.722 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN AnagraficaDAO.listAll - trovati: 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-7-05/06/23 17:31:10.724 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN ChiamataNativa  - trovati: 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-7-05/06/23 17:31:10.725 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN getListaAnagrafica - trovati 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-1-05/06/23 17:31:11.989 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN AnagraficaDAO.listAll - trovati: 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-1-05/06/23 17:31:11.992 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN ChiamataNativa  - trovati: 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-1-05/06/23 17:31:11.993 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN getListaAnagrafica - trovati 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-2-05/06/23 17:31:13.229 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN AnagraficaDAO.listAll - trovati: 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-2-05/06/23 17:31:13.232 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN ChiamataNativa  - trovati: 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-2-05/06/23 17:31:13.233 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN getListaAnagrafica - trovati 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-4-05/06/23 17:31:14.510 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN AnagraficaDAO.listAll - trovati: 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-4-05/06/23 17:31:14.513 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN ChiamataNativa  - trovati: 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-4-05/06/23 17:31:14.514 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN getListaAnagrafica - trovati 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-8-05/06/23 17:31:16.132 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN AnagraficaDAO.listAll - trovati: 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-8-05/06/23 17:31:16.135 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN ChiamataNativa  - trovati: 57 record
http-apr-8080-exec-8-05/06/23 17:31:16.135 INFO  SystemUtils             :100   - 2589-AD20 SCSEDRIN getListaAnagrafica - trovati 57 record
```

**Any idea? Sorry for my bad English!**

Comment: `The problem is that I have different results from the same query called more and more times` ... so what is different about results, are we supposed to guess? It's not clear (to me) based on the output.

Comment: First of all I am the only user of database during the test! As you can see in the log results the database answer for the query is 56 records, next time 57, next time 56 and so on. If I execute the same query using Sqlyog (for example) the result is of 57 record that is what I expect. I don't understand where is executed the the query that responds with 56 records. Is it a cache problem? In this case how can I force Hibernate or CP30 or Mysql to really execute the query? Thank you in advance

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense now. Not sure about the cache aspect, but being only 1 record difference, and not too many records, can you simply print the records to be able to check what the extra might be?

Comment: In this case there is only one record difference but in other case they can be more than one. This depends on how many record I have insert or deleted in a previously operation. This is the very problem: I insert or delete some record, next I select the table content's more and more time without other insert o delete operation and the result change from one query to another. The difference of result is relative to the added/deleted record's. The insert or delete operation are relative to inscription of persons to events and I need to have the correct and complete situation in real time.